# Open HTML document with OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice.org

I create HTML document with C language and then open this document with OpenOffice Calc through shell, like "scalc /home/user/myDoc.html" and I get acceptable Calc table.
During opening of this document "Import options" dialog appears to ask "Select the language to use for import" and then I press button "Automatic" and everything is OK.

Question: Can I get rid of popping "Import options" dialog in order to opening my document and how? By changing some settings in ooCalc or (better) with adding something to html code?

Thanks for any help.